# Are there well known conventions for naming and signatures of C asynchronous functions?

Tags: c, naming-conventions

I'm coming from the C# world.
I had `async` functions there and I need them in C.
I know, I have callbacks. So...

Instead of:

```cs
await DelayAsync(1000); TheNextThing();
```

I say:

```c
delay_async(1000, the_next_thing);
```

I know, it's not the same, but it works similarly enough for my needs. Note that the C# method has the "Async" suffix. Yes, it's a convention. It's not mandatory, but highly recommended.

Now in C I have asynchronous function, and I really need to add some parameters to it. Like options.

So - is one of the signature "more correct" than the other:

1.

```c
my_function_async(my_handle*, void (*callback)(my_handle*), uint8_t option1, uint8_t option2);
```

2. 

```c
my_function_async(my_handle*, uint8_t option1, uint8_t option2, void (*callback)(my_handle*));
```

Are there some commonly acknowledged conventions for such code?

Is using "_async" suffix OK, recommended or maybe frowned upon?

In embedded application it can be misleading - async may suggest it's about asynchronous transmission that is something completely different than asynchronous function. To add even more confusion - my driver just happens to use asynchronous transmission. But it implements both interrupt mode and blocking mode. And I have to give different names for the functions. I'm pretty clueless about naming conventions to take here.

For now I have `foo(handle)` and `foo_async(handle, callback)` pairs of functions. Maybe I should use the word "interrupt"? We all love long names ;) "Int"? Looks confusing. IDK.

My goal is to make it not stand out, as much conforming to well established standards as it gets. The problem is I'm kind of a new kid here.

I think it's not about opinion or personal preferences. I'm just asking are there any well known conventions for that. I tried to google that, but I haven't found the answer.

Comment: This question *is* [opinion-based](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337660/whats-the-minimum-requirement-for-questions-tagged-with-naming-conventions)

Comment: It's a matter of preference what the order of the parameters are.  My advice to you would be to make sure this function is re-entrant if it could be interrupted and called again.

Comment: There is no widespread convention — so any answer that doesn't state "there is no convention", especially one espousing any particular convention, is providing an opinion. The argument sequence is mostly arbitrary, though putting the callback pointer between the two options would be a bit odd. The names are completely arbitrary; there is not much code in C that uses asynchronous processing outside of asynchronous I/O. The POSIX functions for asynchronous I/O have the prefix `aio_`. (It isn't obvious to a non-C# programmer what the `await` sequence does.) Use whatever convention appeals to you.